# I am trying to get the difference between two values from the same table, Min and Max is SSRS 2017

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to get the difference between Id1 and Id2 pulled from a SQL table via the following query:

```
SELECT
[Id],
[CollectedDate],
[DataValue]

INTO #tmpPollingStorage2 --- temporary table
FROM
    [dbo].[PollingStorage]
WHERE
    ((DataSource = 35) or (DataSource = 36) or (DataSource = 37) or (DataSource = 38)) AND 
(CollectedDate >= (@prmStartDate) OR (@prmStartDate) IS NULL) AND (CollectedDate <= (@prmEndDate) OR 
(@prmEndDate) IS NULL) AND (DataSource = (@prmDataSource) OR (@prmDataSource) IS NULL)  
(
Select TOP 1 MAX(DataValue) as Id1 FROM [#tmpPollingStorage2]
UNION ALL
Select TOP 1 MIN(DataValue) as Id2 FROM [#tmpPollingStorage2]
)
 DROP TABLE #tmpPollingStorage2
```

I have tried to add a text box with ID2 and use an expression to produce Id1 - Id2 via the text box as well as just a straight equation. I believe my issue is that the data is actually in one column. Can you assist please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simplify your query to something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        [Id], [CollectedDate],
        Id1 = MAX([DataValue]) OVER(),
        Id2 = MIN([DataValue]) OVER()
    FROM
        [dbo].[PollingStorage]
    WHERE
        DataSource IN (35,36,37,38)
        AND (CollectedDate >= @prmStartDate OR @prmStartDate IS NULL) 
        AND (CollectedDate <= @prmEndDate OR @prmEndDate IS NULL)
        AND (DataSource = @prmDataSource OR @prmDataSource IS NULL)
```

This will give you 4 columns, Id1 and Id2 will be identical on each row so in SSRS if they are being used in an aggregate scope you can set an expression something like

```
=FIRST(Fields!Id1.Value) - FIRST(Fields!Id2.Value)
```

You could even just do all of this in SQL but as I don;t know what you requirements are it's hard to tell the best approach.

If this does not help, post a sample of data and the expected output from the sample and it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you Alan, When I run your query in either SQL or SSRS I receive an error. In SQL the error is "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'FROM'".   As for the requirements they should be fairly simple. the difference between Id1 and Id2. I have tried the expression you have above and have followed some suggestions regarding dropping Id2 into a text box and changing the expression parameter to the text box name.value.  All to no avail.I am working on your suggestion now to see if I can get it to work, you hit on my issue which has been getting Id1 and 2 into 2 different columns on the same row.

Comment: Alan,I was able to get it working. Thank you very much.

Comment: AH yes, I just noticed the extra comma (sorry). I'll edit the answer now so it's more useful to others in the future

Comment: If this solved the issue, could you please mark this answer as accepted. this help others when looking for solutions